# Ubuntu 12.04 failure to update

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I am trying to update my ubuntu with "sudo-apt-get update"
Below is the error I am getting. Kindly help me resolve.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                                                           
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                      
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke precise Release.gpg                                                                                                    
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke precise-security Release.gpg                                                                                           
  Unable to connect to 172.16.63.15:3128:
Err http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke precise-updates Release.gpg                                                                                            
  Unable to connect to 172.16.63.15:3128:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                                      
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                                  
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://apt.insynchq.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                                        
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                                           
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Err http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                                                                                         
  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 172.16.63.15:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 172.16.63.15:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.63.15:3128 (172.16.63.15), connection timed out

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Comment: Try after change download server from software & updates (choose best server) and make sure you are properly connected to internet

Comment: I am connected to the internet. I chose main server and still get the same error

Comment: Can you browse the internet on firefox for instance? And welcome to AskUbuntu Timo - UbuntuKenya damu :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy server (172.16.63.15:3128) can not be reached. Check if it's set up correctly or try to connect directly.

Comment: How do i change that proxy server or remove it completely?

Comment: Try `export http_proxy=` before running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: That doesnt seem to help. I get the same same error again!

Answer (score 0):

The server `security.ubuntu.com` is just not responding right now. Try another server.

Go to System Settings, and click on Software and Updates. On the first tab, locate the dropdown labelled Download from and choose another location for your downloads, or Main Server.

I solved it before like this.

Comment: I dont see "Software & updates" there. :( check this screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JeS9ycEE3BcGVrNkdfVmdwMmc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried searching for it.

Comment: Ok. Now i found it via Software center then i switched to "main server" but still i get the same error

Comment: Oki i recommend you to check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure